# Помогите с выведением остатка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Была идея в том, что вводятся числа для деление
если есть остаток выводится с остатком и У МЕНЯ ВЫЛЕЗАЕТ ОШИБКА

```
from math import *
print("Write numbers to be division")
my_num=int(input())
my_num1=int(input())
my_num2=floor(my_num/my_num1)
my_num3=my_num%my_num1
if my_num3==0:
print(my_num,"/",my_num1,"=",my_num2)
else:
print(my_num,"/",my_num1,"=",my_num2,"remainder(ostatok)",my_num3)
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код нормально и укажите, в чём проблема

Comment: Была идея в том, что вводятся числа для деление, если есть остаток выводится с остатком,а если нет то без, АЛЛО

Comment: Пожалуйста, выполните указанные действия с помощью кнопки править под вопросом

Comment: довольны, в чём ошибка?

Comment: `from math import floor`?

Comment: это есть, но всё равно ошибка

Comment: В таком виде ваш вопрос скорее всего закроют, если не найдутся добрые люди и не приведут его в надлежащую форму

Comment: Поставить Tab перед `print` в `if` и `else`?

Comment: вы можете не докапываться и помочь с кодом

Comment: `У МЕНЯ ВЫЛЕЗАЕТ ОШИБКА` - какая ошибка? Мы должны угадать? Представьте, вы приходите к врачу, и говорите: "помогите, У МЕНЯ ЧТО-ТО БОЛИТ, но что именно болит я вам не скажу"

Comment: отступы совсем нетак

Comment: @Стас, сделал откат правок, потому что это по сути исправление кода, и после исправления никаких ошибок не наблюдается. Если есть желание помочь автору вопроса - пишите ответ, но не исправляйте код в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто напишите вот так, и не будет никакой ошибки:

```
from math import *

print("Write numbers to be division")

my_num = int(input())
my_num1 = int(input())
my_num2 = floor(my_num / my_num1)
my_num3 = my_num % my_num1

if my_num3 == 0:
    print(my_num, "/", my_num1, "=", my_num2)
else:
    print(my_num, "/", my_num1, "=", my_num2, "remainder(ostatok)", my_num3)
```

Ну и само собой так красивее: )
Проблема была в том, что вы вообще не правильно ставите пробели, загуглите об этом, и жить станет гораздо легче